# What smart contract language does IOTA use?

Tags: legacy-protocol, smart-contract

What smart contract language does IOTA use? Solidity?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOTA will use a smart contract language called Abra - which is an *intermediate trinary-based functional programming language*.

More information on Abra can be found [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/qubic-quorum-based-computations-powered-by-iota-66aa61ca4916#71d9).

Comment: Read the link! Thanks. How will the syntax look like? Will it be like solidity as I am familiar with solidity.

Comment: Not much info about the syntax yet. But CfB said if you know FPGA programming, you will be able learn Abra in a few days.

Comment: Is that a hint that it might be a sub(super)-set of Verilog?

Comment: @Helmar , And can we currently deploy a smart contract in IOTA ? or Is it still underway and in progress?(https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/2438/1928)