# Smart Contract for IOTA: Is it finally possible to deploy a contract in IOTA in practice? Or still underway?

Tags: smart-contract

I heard before that IOTA decided to add the possibility of developing and deploying  the smart contract in IOTA (Like Ethereum) with a specific language called "Abra", and it was promised to be run at the end of 2018.

Can we currently deploy a smart contract  in IOTA ? or Is it still underway and in progress?

Comment: Qubic is still on the way. And I don't think it should ever support Ethereum-style smart contracts (i..e. being strongly linked with balances and validating what financial transactions are valid) - rather some way of paying nodes for computational tasks.